# IPython: Plot graphics when running an external script within IPython in pylab mode

Tags: ipython

I have a Python script `myscript.py` which looks like this:

```
$ cat myscript.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2])
```

When running IPython in *pylab* mode:

```
$ ipython --pylab
```

Executing the following command (line 2 in my script) will result in the graphics popping up in a new window:

```
In []: plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2])
```

On the other hand, when running `myscript.py`, the image will not be shown:

```
In []: %run myscript.py
```

Is there any way to change this behaviour and force IPython to show the images generated within the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing external scripts within IPython's console with the `%run` command, those scripts will be executed in **not** interactive mode. Therefore,

```
plt.show()
```

must be added in the script in order to show the generated graphics.